# Exact Target Marketing Cloud Retrieve Automation Status sur Fuel SDK Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, exacttarget

I use Rails for development and the gem FuelSDK to retrieve information from Exact Target Marketing cloud (salesforce, via API).

I can retrieve information from campaigns, mails, etc... but I can't find a direct way to retrieve data from Automations (Automation studio), for exemple, the get the status of job.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Comment: I'll post my question on the salesforce stackexchange. Thanks.